# Help with <table> tag

Tags: html

I have the following code

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 50%; border:1px solid #ccc!important; border-color:#000!important;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: 10px;"><em>Previous editions are obsolete</em></span></span></td>
            <td style="width: 50%; border:1px solid #ccc!important; border-color:#000!important;">
            <div style="text-align: right;"><span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;"><span style="font-size: 10px;">Credit Union Name:</span></span></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

in the output I am seeing gap between two table. Can anyone help me how to remove the gap between the two table.

[image]

Comment: you can post this question on stackoverflow

Comment: it's a margin issue. Tables add margin and padding by default. you have to set it to 0

Answer (score 1):

This is not a gap between two *tables* but between the two *cells* of your table. You can easily remove that (or modify it) by adding `border-spacing: 0` to the table style.

By the way, I would also remove the `<div>` from inside the second cell. If you really need a block element there, you can use `display: block`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also remove the gap by setting the border-collapse: collapse to the table style.